# javascript: mouse events do not working with large area

Tags: javascript

I have a html file like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drag-Drop</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script language="javascript" src="myJavascript.js"></script>
 </head>
    <body height="10000" width="10000" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px">
  <svg id="svgBackground" height="10000" width="10000" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px">
  </svg>
  <svg id="svgTempArrows" height="10000" width="10000" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px">
  </svg>
  <svg id="svgForwardArrows" height="10000" width="10000" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px">
  </svg>
  <svg id="svgBackwardArrows" height="10000" width="10000" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px">
  </svg>
  <svg id="svgArrowHeads" height="10000" width="10000" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px">
  </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in myJavascript.js I have:

```js
window.onload = function background()
{
   ...
   var elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagNameNS(svgNS, 'svg'));
   elements.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener("mousedown", startDraw);
  el.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
  el.addEventListener("mouseup", endDraw);
   });
   
   function startDraw(ev)
   {
      ...
   }
   
     function draw(ev)
   {
      ...
   }
   
     function endDraw(ev)
   {
      ...
   }
```

It has worked, but It only works in one area in a web page (The mouse envents seem only effect in upper area of web page).
I don't know why is it. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: `left: 0px; top: 0px`. All your svg tag is in same position (top :0, left: 0)

Comment: becasue I want to draw lines on a background, so I did it as you see
And I also remove some svg, keep only one svg tag, but It still has this issue ^^

Comment: I can't run your codebase which pulls from github because of lacking library(drag_drop.js). But you need carefully with use var in for loop. Use `let` is better

Comment: yes, I forgot rename the javascript file, It should be pta_gui.js. I fixed it and push in git again. Now, you can pull and run it ^6 thank you

Comment: I think that I have solved the issue. It's the issue about offset change when have the scroll. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem here?

> document.getElementsByTagNameNS(svgNS, 'svg')

and your position all the same

Comment: I removed some svg tag and keep only 1 svg tag, but it still has this issue

Comment: I think that I have solved the issue. It's the issue about offset change when have the scroll. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have done some changes to your code and now it is working fine with me
i used jquery

```
var elements = $('svg');

for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
   elements[i].addEventListener("mousedown", startDraw);
   elements[i].addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
   elements[i].addEventListener("mouseup", endDraw);
 }
```

Comment: Sure let me check it out! :)

Comment: @giahuyphan I have requested some changes to your code on Git hub Kindly check it and let me know if it helps

Comment: @ MsulemanKhan It still that. I want to draw arrows by ckick-move-release mouse, It works true in under part of page, but in above page it does not work. You can run my code to know issue

Comment: I think I will try fixing it myself ^^ thanks for your help

Comment: I think that I have solved the issue. It's the issue about offset change when have the scroll. Thanks